# Sharepoint API authentication without OAuth

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api, oauth

I'm trying to make an integration work between JIRA and Sharepoint to populate values in a custom field in JIRA from querying the Sharepoint API, but the JIRA Addon I'm using to  **does not** support *OAuth*. It **does** support *basic authentication* and *adding headers and cookies*.

I managed to test it by passing the cookies *fedauth* and *rtfa* (I got those by inspecting the web requests on my browser), but those are supposed to expire soon. Plus, my account will be removed as soon as I finish this assignment.

Is there any header that I can use to authenticate, with tokens that will never expire? Or is there any way to enable basic authentication for only a specific user?

(I'm new to Sharepoint btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sharepoint online, you can do it by MS Flow,
Make a flow with http trigger, witch you can call from anywhere, 
the connection between flow and sharepoint will be authenticated by the flow.
And the result, list items or what do you want you put to the response of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you are trying to extract information from a SharePoint list but you are running the process in JIRA so, you are querying SP from JIRA.
In this case, I recommend you to use [Graph API for sites and lists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) and the authentication must be based on OAuth but using a clientId and clientSecret, that avoids the use of any user account and its password.